# Screen should fit for all iphones and ipads in portrait mode

Tags: swift

I am not able to fit my screen according to all iphones and ipads. Please suggest me some link relate to that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to resolve my issue. I used size classes and auto layout(multiplier) to fit it in all iphone sizes.  Thanx

Answer (score 1):

When you create your project, did you select Universal under Devices? 
If not, you can change by clicking on your project, then click your project name under TARGETS. Select the General and look under Deployment Info for Devices and change it to universal.

Here's the documentation for this.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

If you already did this, then it could be a problem with your constraints. To learn how to work with them here you have a tutorial that may be useful to you about working with constraint and autolayout:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at size classes ! Cheers
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html